# Am getting Nullpointer exception on 'RunAs' via TestNG[installed as plug in eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNG_sample {

    @BeforeTest
    public void Test1() {   
        System.out.println("am executin test1");
    }
}
```

What do i do? to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you create this as testNG class or simple java class?

Comment: Please share more details on the error, like stacktrace.

Comment: i used simple java class .Error details:An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestNG_sample".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps.

•Help
•Install new software...
•What is already installed?
•Select the TestNG M2E software and click uninstall

Hope this helps!